# How Is A Free Account Charged When Using Microsoft Azure Products?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I can find this answer right away by searching the price of each product when in use. However, it is only a general price but not completely detailed. I posted this question only for more details on the issuer's pricing. And also because I am currently using a free package. I have registered to use the product for less than 1 month, exactly on March 2, 2019 with a free package of $ 200. 2 days ago, I created Windows Server 2016 Datacenter virtual machine, Standard D2s v3, 2 vcpus, 8 GB memory. Today I received the message: "Your free credit is about to expire". I wonder if one thing is too expensive. I also do not understand how my product package is priced, because when I choose the product size, I get a message with the content: Try to make use of your free resources reason ... So I choose that kind of size. The problem here is that I want to know if there is a difference between the price of a free account and a free account. If at such a price without an early announcement with content like: the price of this product, if you use it, your credit will run out. Hope to get an explanation to better understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: The free tier only covers certain things: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/

Answer (score 4):

The $200 credit expires after 30 days. You get warnings a few days before that expiration, which should have been explained in the text of the email you received.

Comment: The problem is that I have been using it for only 1 day, and I received the notice, along with the content saying: "Only 2 days left for your credit to run out ..." It's too fast! Too fast, I have not been able to enjoy my newly registered products. This is like I have to swallow a delicious dish, but not chew it.

Comment: @KyleLevine You need a credit card check to activate your free account, so make sure you close your instance before it go on your CC by the way

Comment: @KyleLevine Yes, I don't like the fact that it's only for 30 days either. I couldn't use a $200 credit that quickly. Google gives a $300 credit that lasts for one year...